# SwiftUI localization doesn't work shows only keys Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

i am working on app using SwiftUI in Xcode, and i want to localise it, but i have an issue.
I already done all steps from youtube video

1. Added localizations in Project -> info -> localizations
2. Created 2 localization files
3. Filled it like "hll" = "Hello";
   etc.

and when i build an app i have only keys instead values (hll instead Hello), so i tried Text("hll") and Text(LocalizedStringKey("hll")). What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the `Localizable.strings` file in your project. There is where `LocalizedStringKey` looks for the keys/values as a default.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/localizedstringkey

If you want to define a different file use the

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey, tableName: String?, bundle: Bundle?, comment: StaticString?)
```

initializer and the `tableName` should match your `.strings` file name.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that depends on name, renamed it from localize.strings to Localizable.strings and it works

Comment: Good answer you save my time

Comment: @KavinduDissanayake glad to help. Please upvote any answers you find useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Text {
public init<S>(_ text: S) where S : StringProtocol {
    let text = String(text)
    
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "en", ofType: "lproj")
    let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
    
    let translated = NSLocalizedString(text, tableName: "Localizable", bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")

    self.init(verbatim: translated)
}
```