# how to localize a picker to another language?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, picker

```
@State var selectedSpace : FreeSpace = .Big_Bag

     Picker("", selection: $selectedSpace) {
                            ForEach(FreeSpace.allCases) { FreeSpace in
                                Text(FreeSpace.rawValue.capitalized)
                            }
                        }.environment(\.locale, Locale.init(identifier: "az-Arab"))
                          .foregroundColor(Color("Color"))
                          .padding(.trailing)
```

Knowing that the pickerValues

```
enum FreeSpace: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
        case Big_Bag, Small_Bag
        var id: Self { self }
    }
```

i'm trying to convert what is inside the picker to arabic and can't find a solution it is always displayed in english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From apple doc :

> If you intialize a text view with a variable value, the view uses the init(*:) initializer, which doesn’t localize the string. However, you can request localization by creating a LocalizedStringKey instance first, which triggers the init(*:tableName:bundle:comment:) initializer instead:

```
// Don't localize a string variable...
Text(writingImplement)

// ...unless you explicitly convert it to a localized string key.
Text(LocalizedStringKey(writingImplement))
```

That means that you must use :

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey(FreeSpace.rawValue.capitalized))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but still didn't work 

Comment: @Ms.LightWave This answer along with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70879475/swiftui-localization-doesnt-work-shows-only-keys-xcode/70879678#70879678) and the other answer here give you all you need to implement. 1. Activate localizations (other answer) 2. implement the `Localizable.strings` file (link). 3. The use the examples above in the picker.

Comment: thank you it worked the problem was my iphone simulator was lagging and not taking the value ! i tried to uninstall and then install and it worked thank you alot 

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood the concept of iOS localization. In you app you need to provide localizable strings file (usually it is named Localizable.strings), which holds localization values for your supported languages.

So basically in your project settings, you need to enable desired languages (English and Arabic on the screenshot).
[image: languages]

Then you create Localizable.strings file and add it as a resource of your app. Then just make it localizable by clicking localize in File Inspector.

[image: localizable button]

This will let you choose what language you want to use for the current file. Once you make it localizable you can tick what languages to use and you can switch them in Project Navigator.

[image: localized files]

Since now you will put localized texts in its appropriate Localizable file and use its key to access it.

Then if you use `Text(String(localized: "key").uppercased())` you should be fine.

Comment: how does this work incase of picker ? it only works for a pure text ?

Comment: What do you mean by "pure text"? By using `String(localized: "key")` you get a localized string from Localizable.strings based on current system localization and you can use wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can localizated like that **for picker.** But if you setted your picker segments comes from an Array:

let qiuzSegments = [NSLocalizedString("5000 Words", comment: "5000 Kelime"),
NSLocalizedString("Favorite Words", comment: "Favori Kelimeler")]

It's help to Turkish -> English translate.

I mean first string is your target language, second string (comment) is your main app language. **You can set picker localization like that.**

For more information check my Medium page: https://beratridvanasilturk.medium.com/